# How to change the taskbar icon of vbscript message box?

Tags: vbscript

I tried some tools like VBS to EXE, but the message box is still showing [wscript.exe's icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy8NS.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll want to explore developing a HTML Application (.HTA file), then [review the solutions found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175994/can-i-embed-an-icon-to-a-hta-file). HTH.

Comment: Try with vbsedit, you can convert any vbs or hta file and adding an icon to executable

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for being 2.5 years late, but this might help someone else.

Pin `.VBS` files to your *Start Menu* and *Taskbar* in Windows 10

### Add to Start Menu:

- Open File Explorer.
- Navigate to the directory of your VBS file.
- Rename '.vbs' to '.exe'.
- Right-click on the EXE file, then click on 'Pin to Start'.
- Rename '.exe' to '.vbs'.

---

- Open another File Explorer window.
- Navigate to (or copy and paste into nav bar): `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
- Right-click on the VBS shortcut file, then click on 'Properties'.
- Change the TARGET path from [PATH][FILE].exe to [PATH][FILE].vbs.
- Click OK.

### Add shortcut link to the Taskbar:

- Right-click on the VBS shortcut file again, then click on 'Pin to taskbar'.

Found here and then tweaked it a bit:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd2b13ef-2968-4f23-b531-57d1e9d634e3/if-you-guys-have-been-trying-hard-to-pin-vbs-files-to-your-start-menu-in-windows-10-look-no?forum=ITCG